# Slow Canvas Speed Drawing On Big Canvas (5000x5000)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem with slow canvas speed because of the canvas size (5000x5000) I can't find the bottleneck of why it's slow, I just know if the canvas size is smaller it works great! Here is a demo of my code

Original screen size canvas depends on your screen work flawlessly
http://cssdeck.com/labs/e6et3j1x/

A bigger 5000x5000 size canvas (first line drawing is fast! The second+ are slow):
http://cssdeck.com/labs/fq43lzzz

How can I possibly overcome this issue? It's impossible to overcome this should I move to SVG?

1. I have tried clearReact only on visible window size with $().offset() it doesn't seems to be cause of slow speed.
2. I tried to make a smaller temporary canvas and re position it to the visible screen, It seems to be fast but the mouse positions on original 5000x5000 are wrong any way to calculate mouse positions on small canvas to fit the bigger one?

I have researched for hours! If you can help I would really appreciate that. Thank you!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but why does your canvas need to be 5000x5000?

Comment: @Jared It's a kind of drawing app and it has a big canvas, It's actually cannot be less than 5000x5000 so it's important.

Comment: The larger the canvas size the more redrawing (and associated resources) that must be used to achieve the redraw. Sorry, but your issue is almost certainly not code related...your problem is structural--your canvas is large and slow. :-//

Comment: @markE any ideas on solving it? :)

Comment: It's 1:30am local time so I'd be glad to take a look tomorrow. . At first glance you have two 5K x 5K canvases--that's large & expensive. How about, when drawing, scale down the tempCanvas from 5K x 5K to something approaching display size so all drawing is done without scrolling. Then you can scale back up when you draw the tempCanvas to the main canvas. Take this suggestion with a grain of salt because I'm reeeeealy tired! I'll check more tomorrow.

Comment: @markE scaling down the temp canvas helps! :) The problem is to convert the drawing from temp canvas scaled down mouse x,y to the 5Kx5K so I'm not sure about this calculation but if we can fit mouse x,y from any screen resolution to 5Kx5K is should work.

Comment: With this app, do you want to be able to zoom out to view the entire 5k x 5k canvas or are you always working in a smaller window? If there is no zooming, then I'd aim for only drawing (and erasing) an area corresponding to what the user can see.

Comment: @Niddro it's with scrollbars at first and it has the options to zoom out zoom in